# How is rand() and sleep() made in a kernel module?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Like title suggest: how can I make a call to sleep()?

Comment: Chapter 7: http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use get_random_bytes(), similar calls to sleep() also exist for example msleep(), usleep() etc. depending on what you want to do.  Note that *sleep() cannot be used in an atomic context, you will want to use *delay().  Generally you need to think twice before using sleep()/delay() calls in the kernel.

If you are writing a device driver and you want to ensure that the device has finished doing whatever (assuming you can't use an interrupt for that and you need to poll some register or so) then instead of doing msleep(10) consider having a loop going around 5 times with an msleep(2) or similar, poll the register and break out as early as possible.  The time you wait is at least the time you've requested and depends on system load.

Answer (score 0):

dmp 's right.
Keeping all the above points in mind, you could in addition try this simple macro to emulate a sleep(3) kernel call:

```
#ifdef __KERNEL__
/*------------ DELAY_SEC -------------------------*
 * Delays execution for n seconds.
 * MUST be called from process context.
 *------------------------------------------------*/
#define DELAY_SEC(val) \
{ \
    if (!in_interrupt()) {  \
        set_current_state (TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE); \
        schedule_timeout (val * HZ); \
    }   \
}
#endif
```